# What is a better way to submit form details

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am developing an ERP system using PHP as a server side..So I need to be very careful for the security of my website/system. I'll be also using JavaScript for client side validation. So I want to be sure that client has JavaScript turned on, of course I'll be validating the data server side too but I don't want unnecessary server calls, mainly I am concerned about forms..and the data the clients fill in and submit..so what should I use to submit my data?

Default HTML submit and validate here with JavaScript (Note : Useless if JavaScript is turned off by the client)

```
<input type="submit" name="Add Data" />
```

Or submit using an anchor tag `<a>` with help of a JavaScript (I found this meaningful as if JavaScript is turned off he wont be able to submit the data)

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById("form_id").submit();">Submit</a>
```

So are there any bad points if I use `<a>` tag for submitting data or should I stick with the default `submit` button? And if I use `<a>` for submitting the form data, than I'll be able to validate the data using JavaScript?

Comment: What do you think is the benefit of using an anchor instead of button?

Comment: the benefit is if javascript is disabled, user wont be able to submit the form ...so I can force him to switch on javascript in his browser so now even the data will be validated as he needs javascript to be turned on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I want to be sure that client has JavaScript turned on

You can't. Even if you design the system to break without JavaScript, someone could reverse engineer it and submit bad data manually.

> of course I'll be validating the data server side too

That's the solution

> but I don't want unnecessary server calls

If you are getting enough accidental submissions with errors in them from people with JavaScript turned off to give significant performance or load worries, I'll eat my hat.

> Default HTML submit and validate here with JavaScript

Yes. Bind the JavaScript to the `submit` event on the form.

> `<a href="#"`

Don't do that.

> So are there any bad points if I use `<a>` tag for submitting data

- It doesn't look like something that will submit a form
- It doesn't show up in *forms* mode in a screen reader
- It silently fails if the JavaScript doesn't work for any reason

> should I stick with the default submit button?

Yes!

Comment: Awesome answer...so btw you said bind the JavaScript event with submit, you mean `onclick` event or the validation part?

Comment: The client side validation should be performed using the `submit` event (unless you are doing it as you go along with `change` and `keypress` events). There shouldn't be any need for a `click` event.

Answer (score 2):

Use browser defaults whenever possible. Stick with the submit button, and bind your validation to the `submit` event on the form. That way your form works as expected with or without JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't ever view client-side operations as reliable or safe. If I deliberately wanted to, I could just block validation but keep JavaScript working for the submit.

As for your question, it's quite simple: Either you want users to be able to submit without JavaScript or not. This isn't a question on what's "better", it's a question of your requirements.